# What was the trend of forced labor in Germany and its conquered territories during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, economy

All I can find online about forced labor is the fact that by late summer of 1944, "German records listed 7.6 million foreign civilian workers and prisoners of war in the German territory, most of whom had been brought there by coercion."

Source: [Forced labor in Germany during WWII](https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Forced%20labor%20in%20Germany%20during%20World%20War%20II&item_type=topic)

Can someone find a graph or any statistics for each year of the war? I certainly cannot find any other useful data online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are official documents about forced labor here:  http://www.bundesarchiv.de/zwangsarbeit/geschichte/auslaendisch/begriffe/index.html.en   and  http://www.zwangsarbeit-archiv.de/en/index.html

These sources are about forced labor, which is not the same as the number of people brought into concentration camps. The number of 7,6 million is rather the total number of prisoners of war and people in the concentration camps. Forced labor was only a minority part of them.